# modified alert notification sharepoint 2007

Tags: list, alert

How can I modified alert notification 
in sharepoint 2007.

I need to :
1. change field order. 
2. remove column that not relevant to the alert.

**(without using the designer or sharepoint server)**

Comment: Can you detail what specifically you are trying to modify?  Some changes require a radically different level of effort than others

Comment: I added detail.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, what you are looking to do is not easily accomplished within the alerts framework provided by Microsoft.  If you wanted to reskin the alert or perhaps add branding, that is done relatively easily.  However, manipulating the specific fields in the alert messages requires a fair amount of custom coding and very detailed testing.  In the end, you would probably be better off using a Third-Party alert package instead.